# Dependence of decay width on the CKM parameters

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, cp-violation

So what i want to know mainly is when do i use the conjugate? Like when should it be $V_{cd}$ or $V^*_{cd}$? Please look at a pic for example - So should I used conjugate? $V^*$ instead of $V$? [image: Homework] Another example - So should I used conjugate? $V^*$ instead of $V$? [image: Homework] Please answer quickly if possible. This is for my worksheet and I have many other similar questions. If I can just understand one example of when I should use conjugate and when I shouldn't I will be able to do it.

Comment: Well a friend of mine answered that all interactions anti particles have conjugate. So in b) Vus will be V*us

Comment: And apparently that friend was wrong vsince the lecturer told me that interactions going from up type quarks to down type quarks have conjugate. So in b) it will be Vus and V*cs